# compare 2 x509 certificate in java

Tags: java, certificate, arrays, x509certificate

I have been provided a byte array and an X509 certificate.  I can generate X509 certificate from the byte array using below code.

```
CertificateFactory certificatefactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certificatefactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

Please guide me how to verify that the generated X509 with the one which was provided to me.

Comment: If you look up X.509 on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) they walk you through how to validate one.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use `certificate.equals(otherCertificate)` : the `equals()` method will compare them correctly, with a specific implementation for each certificate subclass.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 4):

Do it the other way around. Turn the certificate into bytes (`X509Certificate.getEncoded()`) and just compare the bytes.

But the question is pointless. If the byte array is the input to the certificate factory that produces the certificate, they can't possibly be different.